# mysql database versioning and pt-online-schema-change

Tags: mysql, versioning, liquibase, flyway, pt-online-schema-change

its my first question on stack, than please forgive me if i do something wrong. I look for some tools what i can use for versioning my database. I found nice program for this like Liquibase or Flyway but hear start my problem. Usually to make change on table I use pt-online-schema-change from command linie. None of these tools support command line so I would like to ask if anyone knows another way to workaround this problem, or any other tool that allows it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to call other programs from liquibase: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/execute_command.html but I'm not sure that it is convinient to run all changes this way.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to test but should solve my problem.